# Pulling in categories on eBay using XML API

Tags: php, html, css, xml

Long time lurking first time posting, I am stumped!

I have been attempting to get a dynamic category list on my employers eBay shop for a while now, I have spent a lot of time trawling for answers or pre-written code but came to the conclusion that if I want it done I'm going to have to do it myself (totally fine but time consuming).

Playing with the eBay Dev API testing ground I have managed to pull down the categories that I want. What I am finding difficult is how to then style and organize the results.

This would be easier if I could target the tags that the XML outputs with CSS but as they are non-standard, I can't.

This is what I have written so far, the 'style color:red' was simply to test the div was working and all the required credentials are stored in the 'keys.php' file:

```
<?php
/*  © 2013 eBay Inc., All Rights Reserved */ 
/* Licensed under CDDL 1.0 -  http://opensource.org/licenses/cddl1.php */
require_once('keys.php') ?>
<?php require_once('eBaySession.php') ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<TITLE>GetCatagories</TITLE>

<style type="text/css">
#child {
    color:red;
}
</style>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<?php    
    //SiteID must also be set in the Request's XML
    //SiteID = 3  (US) - UK = 3, Canada = 2, Australia = 15, ....
    //SiteID Indicates the eBay site to associate the call with
    $siteID = 3;
    //the call being made:
    $verb = 'GetStore';
    //Level / amount of data for the call to return (default = 0)
    $detailLevel = 0;


    ///Build the request Xml string
    $requestXmlBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
    $requestXmlBody .= '<GetStoreRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">';
    $requestXmlBody .= "<RequesterCredentials><eBayAuthToken>$userToken</eBayAuthToken></RequesterCredentials>";
    $requestXmlBody .= '</GetStoreRequest>';

    //Create a new eBay session with all details pulled in from included keys.php
    $session = new eBaySession($userToken, $devID, $appID, $certID, $serverUrl, $compatabilityLevel, $siteID, $verb);
    //send the request and get response
    $responseXml = $session->sendHttpRequest($requestXmlBody);
    if(stristr($responseXml, 'HTTP 404') || $responseXml == '')
        die('<P>Error sending request');

    //Xml string is parsed and creates a DOM Document object
    $responseDoc = new DomDocument();
    $responseDoc->loadXML($responseXml);


    //get any error nodes
    $errors = $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName('Errors');

    //if there are error nodes
    if($errors->length > 0)
    {
        echo '<P><B>eBay returned the following error(s):</B>';
        //display each error
        //Get error code, ShortMesaage and LongMessage
        $code = $errors->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('ErrorCode');
        $shortMsg = $errors->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('ShortMessage');
        $longMsg = $errors->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('LongMessage');
        //Display code and shortmessage
        echo '<P>', $code->item(0)->nodeValue, ' : ', str_replace(">", "&gt;", str_replace("<", "&lt;", $shortMsg->item(0)->nodeValue));
        //if there is a long message (ie ErrorLevel=1), display it
        if(count($longMsg) > 0)
            echo '<BR>', str_replace(">", "&gt;", str_replace("<", "&lt;", $longMsg->item(0)->nodeValue));

    }
    else //no errors
    {
        $i = 2;
        while ($i <= 188) {
                echo '<div id="catagories">';
                echo $responseDoc->getElementsByTagName("Name")->item($i++)-     >textContent;
                echo '<BR>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }         
?>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The majority of the above code is credential checking and error management it's really the last 12 or so lines of code that do the heavy lifting.

Currently it has output all of my categories and the corresponding child categories in one long vertical list, ideally I would like to indent  the children and give them a smaller font-size, the easiest way (to my mind) would have been to div them out and apply CSS but I'm beginning to think there is an easier way, any suggestions or comments are welcome at this point,

Thank you for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy to use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) in your project I have developed an [SDK for PHP](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php) that simplifies using the API. The example below will get the store categories in the correct order and output a simple tree using nested `<ol>` elements which can be styles using CSS.

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use \DTS\eBaySDK\Constants;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Services;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Types;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Enums;

$service = new Services\TradingService([
    'credentials' => [
        'appId'  => $appID,
        'devId'  => $devID,
        'certId' => $certID
    ],
    'authToken'   => $userToken,
    'siteId'      => Constants\SiteIds::GB
]);

$request = new Types\GetStoreRequestType();
$request->CategoryStructureOnly = true;

$response = $service->getStore($request);

$html = '';

if (isset($response->Errors)) {
    $html .= '<p>eBay returned the following error(s):<br/>';
    foreach ($response->Errors as $error) {
        $html .= sprintf(
            "%s: %s<br/>%s<br/>",
            $error->SeverityCode === Enums\SeverityCodeType::C_ERROR ? 'Error' : 'Warning',
            htmlentities($error->ShortMessage),
            htmlentities($error->LongMessage)
        );
    }
    $html .= '</p>';
}

if ($response->Ack !== 'Failure') {
    $categories = iterator_to_array($response->Store->CustomCategories->CustomCategory);
    usort($categories, 'sortCategories');
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $html .= '<ol>'.buildCategory($category).'</ol>';
    }
}

function buildCategory($category)
{
    $html = '<li>';
    $html .= htmlentities($category->Name);
    $children = iterator_to_array($category->ChildCategory);
    usort($children, 'sortCategories');
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $html .= '<ol>'.buildCategory($child).'</ol>';
    }
    $html .= '</li>';

    return $html;
}

function sortCategories($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->Order === $b->Order) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a->Order < $b->Order) ? -1 : 1;
}

echo <<< EOF_HTML
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Example</title>
      <style>
        ol {
          list-style-type: none;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        $html
    </body>
  </html>
EOF_HTML;
```